# Undefined property: Users::$Usersa Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object

Tags: codeigniter, properties, call, models, member

I'm using codeigniter framework and I'm getting this error when I've submitted my form:

> Message: Undefined property: Users::$Usersa
>  Filename:
>   controllers/users.php
>  Line: 44
>  Fatal error: Call to a
>   member function insert() on a non-object

Users Controller (section that's broken):

```
$this->load->model('usersa');

$register = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email')
    );

    // validation stuff

    if ($this->input->post())
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        } else {
            $this->Usersa->insert($register); // This is line 44
        }
```

Usersa Model (this file is located in application/models)

```
class Usersa extends MY_Model {

var $table = 'users';

function __construct() {  
    parent::__construct();
}
}
```

MY_Model (located in applications/core)

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model{

protected $table = '';


function __construct() {  
    parent::__construct();
}

function insert() {
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $register);

}
}
```

The table data is getting passed through fine and I'm pretty sure the register data is as well I just can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the model as `"usera"` - but referencing it as `$this->Usera` - you should references it lowercased:

`$this->usersa->insert($register);`

Alternately, you can pass the name you'd like to reference the model at with the 2nd parameter as illustrated @ http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html:

`$this->load->model('usersa','some_model_name');`

`$this->some_model_name->insert(...);`

Comment: Thanks for that, I did initially have it lowercase and then changed it because I was receiving another error.